# Can I create foreign key constraints from singe FK to multiple PK

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Currently, I have `two configuration tables` that stores two different kinds of configurations, however, both have an `ID` column. I have one table called `Deactivation`. Any configuration I want to deactivate I can add `ID` of that configuration table into this table.

Structure of the database is as follow.

[image]

My question is Can I create two FK constraints that refer,

```
- ID (FK) to T1_ID (PK)
- ID (FK) to T2_ID (PK)
```

(single child to multiple parents)

So, `deactivation` table should not be allowed insertion of any `id` which is not in either `T1` or `T2`. But If `ID` found in any of that table insertion should be done.

Thanks

Comment: You should create T1_ID and t2_ID field in Deactivations and put foreign key for each other. If you want to use same ID: first it can create conflict if both table has same ID sequences. Second you can't make foreign key.

Comment: @ZekiGumus thanks for this suggestion. However, I am unable to change the structure of the tables. My concern is to restrict unnecessary IDs insertion into Deactivation tables. Is there any workaround with this structure?

Comment: A FK is when values must appear in a certain other spot. That's not what you want. So don't use "FK" for that. Using two FKs from two fields is a faq--google re multiple/many/two FKs to multiple/many/two tables. But it's usually an anti-pattern for subtyping/inheritance. That's a faq too. Google re sql/database subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. PS If you can't change the tables add a table of all ids or use triggers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: @philipxy I will keep that in mind regarding 'not use images'

Comment: @philipxy your suggested thread shows inheritance (single parent to multiple children) however, in my case its multiple parents to a single child.

Comment: It would actually help more if, rather than using T1 and T2, you described more clearly the types of real world objects/data being modelled here

Comment: The entity type of each of the two tables is a subtype of the entity type of the one table. Each of the 2 tables holds values of one *type* of value that goes in the one table. Your "child of" means "is a subtype of".  Try some of the designs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got your answer already, from the comments, but here as a direct statement:

Relational databases Foreign/Primary key mechanism is not intended to maintain and enforce this kind of relationship between tables. You'll have to do something custom with a trigger on Deactivations, that checks the value being inserted into Deactivations is present in T1 or T2 and permits the insert if it is/rejects it if not.

You'll also have to consider coding up something in T1 and T2 to deal with updates/deleted (cascade them?) and collisions (what if `T1 id = 1` and `T2 id = 2`, but then you change T2 ID to also be 1? What if an ID present in T1, representing one thing, is inserted into T2 representing a different thing? Does the new thing in T2 automatically become deactivated? Does my phone stop working because someone stopped paying their contract on their tablet?)

Answer (score 0):

I think your relationship is backwards.  Basically, you want `deactivations` (or some other table) to have the primary key.  Then, this can be shared among the other tables:

```
create table deactivations (
     deactivationId int auto_increment primary key,
     . . .
);

create table config1 (
     config1Id int primary key,
     . . . 
     constraint fk_config1_config1Id foreign key (config1Id) references deactivations(deactivationId)
);

create table config2 (
     config2Id int primary key,
     . . . 
     constraint fk_config2_config2Id foreign key (config2Id) references deactivations(deactivationId)
);
```

This is not 100% what you need, because a `deactivationId` could be shared between the two tables.  There are ways around this, but alas in MySQL, such a check requires triggers.

If you still want to go with your solution, you can use a generated column:

```
create table deactivations (
    config1Id int,
    config2Id int,
    id int generated always as (coalesce(config1Id, config2Id)),
    constraint fk_deactivations_config1Id as foreign key (config1Id) references config1(config1Id),
    constraint fk_deactivations_config2Id as foreign key (config2Id) references config2(config2Id)
);
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support check constraints, so you require a trigger to guarantee that exactly one but not both of the ids are not null.